# Python 3 serial search through text file only finds one result - why is my search loop not correctly finding subsequent items?

Tags: python

I am trying to get my program to ask the user to enter product codes for some items and then for the program to look up the codes in a text file and present the items code/name/price on the screen.

My code will find the first code entered, but any subsequent codes entered are never found - the program only ever displays the first item that the user is searching for.

Why does my code fail to find and display more than one item?

I have a txt file with three lines:

```
12312356 product1 1.50
76576543 product2 6.20
98765423 product3 2.20
```

and a python program with the code:

```
        item_list = []
        item_quantity = []
        item_order = True
        while item_order == True:
            item_code = input("What is the code of the product you require? ")
            item_list.append(item_code)
            quantity = int(input("What quantity: "))
            item_quantity.append(quantity)
            repeat = input("Would you like to enter another item? (Y/N): ")
            if repeat == "N":
                item_order = False

        with open("stockfile.txt", "r") as f:
            for x in range(len(item_list)):
                product_found = False
                for a_line in f:
                    if item_list[x] in a_line:
                        print(a_line, end="")
                        product_found = True
                if product_found == False:
                    print("Product with code", item_list[x], "not found!")
```

Comment: you need `f.seek(0)` at the end of each loop to reset the pointer, a better options would be to make a set of item_list and use in looping over the file once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open a file, then for every request you read all the file, but after the first request is processed you are at end of file, so when you iterate again on the file to process the following user request the body of the `for a_line in f:` is never processed.

You may

1. put the `with open...` *inside* the `for x in...` loop
2. process the file autonomously, using e.g. a dictionary

   ```
   d = {code:[name,price] for code, name, price in [l.split() for l in f]}
   ```

   before the `for x ...` loop, and in the body just test for

   ```
   if something in d:
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I would write it the other way around.

```
 with open("stockfile.txt", "r") as f:
            for a_line in f:
                # to get the product name
                product = a_line.split(" ")[1]
                if product in item_list:
                    item_list.remove(product)

            if len(item_list)>0:
                for product in item_list:
                     print("Product with code", product, "not found!")
```